# Blender equivalent to “select similar” in Max

Tags: selection-tools, object-mode, select

I'm 3Ds Max user trying to make a move to Blender. I use "select similar" function in Max a lot when I need to group similar objects/ polygons into a layer or group for viewport management result and usually get a satisfying results in Max, but NOT in Blender using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to achieve the same intention.  Is there any method I did not know I should learn in Blender to achieve the same result like "select similar" in Max?

edit:
My modeling workflow sometimes is: sketchUp -> Max. I tried to find every every equivalent aspect in Blender of my old workflow ritual in Max (e.g. move polygons into collections and managing colections hierarchy as eq. of grouping some polygons into layers and grouping various objects/ elements and so on).
What i still don’t find is: how to select similar object in Blender just like in Max?
I know that there are Shift-G & Shift-L which are for the same purpose but their result are not quite satisfying as there as i got in Max, for example:

When you have many 2D tree in Max (converted from Skecthup), and you want to select them you can just select one or some of them then ->right click-> select similar then boom! all the similar 2D trees selected. This are also working well in many other object (other than 2D) “select similar” case.

But i never got satisfying results using Shift-G and/or Shift-L in Blender to achieve it. I was wondering if there are some ex-Max users here knew there is another workflow to achieve the results i need.

note: this question is for expert Blender user who has 3ds Max experience, otherwise you might have a difficulty to grasp what i mean in the question.

Comment: Hi. Can you explain why Shift+G and Shift+L aren't doing what you want? Thanks.

Comment: Agree with Ray, What "select similar" does in 3ds max *exactly* and what's your "intention"?

Comment: Hi @RayMairlot & brockmann, 
sorry i must have been explain earlier.
Whenever you want to tidy up your viewport & try to group similar object/ poligon into layers, you never have much difficulties to select a bunch of instanced objects converted from other 3d app e.g. SketchUp things like: e.g. bushes, rooster, 2d trees, rocks, and so on.. by using select just one of them then pick "select similar" on right click..
But in Blender i can not found any satisfying result when using Shift+G or Shift+L functions.. perhaps i didn't know how to use the trick with them.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into the *Select* menu:

[image]

Comment: yea i saw those and didn't much of helps @brockmann

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. You can create a new collection and put anything you want in there for easy access. Select Linked (Shift-L) is used for selecting things by shared property, such as selecting every mesh object that has the exact same material data-block assigned. I don't know how "Select Similar" worked in Max, not even after reading your explanation.

Comment: hi @R-800 thanks for your question. I hope my response is not waaaay to late for too  late for this lol..

Comment: Hi @R-800, thanks for your comment. I hope i'm not waaay to late to explain my response :-p

Comment: I'm in progress to move to Blender from Max, but found this prolonged for my case just by case like this for one of the examples..
My modeling workflow sometimes is: sketchUp -> Max. I tried to find every every equivalent aspect in Blender of my old workflow ritual in Max (e.g. move polygons into collections and managing colections hierarchy as eq. of grouping some polygons into layers and grouping various objects/ elements and so on).
What i still don’t find is: how to select similar object in Blender just like in Max?

Comment: I know that there are Shift-G & Shift-L which are for the same purpose but their result are not quite satisfying as there as i got in Max, for example:
When you have many 2D tree in Max (converted from Skecthup), and you want to select them you can just select one or some of them then ->right click-> select similar then boom! all the similar 2D trees selected. This are also working well in many other object (other than 2D) “select similar” case.

Comment: But i never got satisfying results using Shift-G and/or Shift-L in Blender to achieve it. I was wondering if there are some ex-Max users here knew there is another workflow to achieve the results i need.

Comment: select pattern works sometime, but not quite what i expect as a solution there..
i'm still look for the better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question, this case was solved satisfactory by creating a custom script to do that.
[Here](https://blenderartists.org/t/select-similar-objects-by-number-of-vertices/1110517) is the link